# CGContextDrawPath - color ignored in ios7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

The following code worked as expected in ios6 (I'm drawing a line graph in a drawRect method of a custom UIView)

```
//evaluate if the cross is inside the envelope
        BOOL crossIsInside  = CGPathContainsPoint(envelopePath, NULL, CGPointMake(crossX, crossY), NO);
        CGContextSetStrokeColor (cgx, (crossIsInside) ? CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor]CGColor]) :
                                                        CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor]CGColor]));


        // draw an X
        CGContextMoveToPoint(cgx, crossX-crossSize, crossY-crossSize);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgx,crossX+crossSize, crossY+crossSize);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(cgx, crossX-crossSize, crossY+crossSize);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgx,crossX+crossSize, crossY-crossSize);
        CGContextDrawPath(cgx, kCGPathStroke);
```

The initial evaluation works, but the lines come out black (not red or green).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that `CGContextSetStrokeColor` no longer seems to work (although that's not documented).  Replacing it with `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` (and changing the arguments appropriately) fixed the problem.

Comment: Your little bit of test code seemed to work for me on iOS 7…  Is it possible that your stroke color *space* is gray?  What happens if you call `CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(cgx, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB());` prior to setting the stroke color?  (Note that if you actually use that technique you should make sure to release the color space too!)

Comment: It looks like setting the architecture to arm64 actually causes the problem. I'm fixing a legacy project for appstore submission and iOS 9, the issue with CGContextSetStrokeColor only appears once I set arm64.